# appending Image to a table row in mvc using jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Why am I getting an error

> variable path doesn't exist in the current context, `@Url.Content(path)`.

My code looks like this.

```
$.getJSON('/config/getSignAll/' + profileid, function (data) {
     $.each(data, function (i, sign) {
        var path = "~/Content/img/" + sign.SignUrl;
        $("#signDiv").append("<tr><td>" + sign.SignDetails + "</td><td><img src='@Url.Content(path)' id='imageSign' alt='' height='100' width='200' /> </td></tr>");  
     });
});
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: Razor code (`@Url.Content()`) is parsed on the server before its sent to the view/ `path` is a javascript variable which does not even exist at that point, hence the error.

Comment: Thanx alot..Mr.Darren Davies....but look var sourcePath = '@Url.Content(path)';//Here also shows the name path doesn't exist in the current context. Is there any way to solve this??

Comment: Yea..You are right Stephen Muecke. I want to know that is there any way to fix the problem.I'm new to mvc#jquery

Comment: As a side note, using a single quote for JS strings results in cleaner code, particularly when constructing html strings where the double quotation mark has a special meaning (attribute value wrapper)

Comment: Just pass the correct full path in the data so all you need is something like `... <img src=" + sign.Path + " ...` - you can use `UrlContent()` in the controller method to generate it (or look at Amits answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your URL mapping function over to the constant part.

```
$.getJSON('/config/getSignAll/' + profileid, function (data) {
     $.each(data, function (i, sign) {
        var path = "@Url.Content("~/Content/img/")" + sign.SignUrl;
        $("#signDiv").append("<tr><td>" + sign.SignDetails + "</td><td><img src='"+path+"' id='imageSign' alt='' height='100' width='200' /> </td></tr>");  
     });
});
```